# Restrict Django Rest Framework for all users except super users

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Can I restrict my Django Rest Framework to be only accessed by super users?

Can I add a decorator to the urls so that the url is only accessed by super users:

```
url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
```

Comment: use `login_required` or `permission_classes`

Comment: Write your own permission class and use it in views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to allow any staff member to access the API, then it's easy

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
    )
}
```

For super user, there isn't a built in permissions class, but we can make one easily.

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class SuPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_superuser
```

and then

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'myapp.permissions.SuPermission',
    )
}
```